# Why dfs using stack is not giving correct result

Tags: graph, stack, depth-first-search

[See DFS image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXbXX.jpg)

[image]

I am using stack to print sequence of dfs. According to input and that image of graph, sequence is 1 2 4 8 5 6 3 7 . But My code is giving output as 1 2 4 8 7 6 5 3 . Can anyone explain how can i fix it??

```
Input:
8 10
1 3
1 2
2 5
2 4
3 7
3 6
4 8
5 8
6 8
7 8


Correct Output:

Sequence: 1 2 4 8 5 6 3 7
```

My Code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int>edges[100];
stack<int>q;
vector<int>item;
int level[100],parent[100],visited[100],tn;



void dfs(int s)
{
    int j,k,fr;
    q.push(s);
    level[s]=0;
    for(j=1;j<=tn;j++)
    {
        visited[j]=0;
    }
    visited[s]=1;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        fr=q.top();
        q.pop();
        item.push_back(fr);
        for(k=0;k<edges[fr].size();k++)
        {
            if(visited[edges[fr][k]]==0)
            {
                 q.push(edges[fr][k]);
                 //cout<<"Pushed="<<fr<<"="<<edges[fr][k];
                 visited[edges[fr][k]]=1;
            }


        }

        //cout<<endl;



    }
}


int main()
{
    int i,e,p,n,u,v,f,m;
    cin>>tn>>e;
    for(i=1;i<=e;i++)
    {
        cin>>u>>v;
        edges[u].push_back(v);
        edges[v].push_back(u);
    }
    dfs(1);
    cout<<"Sequence="<<endl;
    for(m=0;m<item.size();m++)
    {
        cout<<item[m];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Code is showing this output: 1 2 4 8 7 6 5 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marking of the nodes as visited in the implementation contains a bug; the function can be rewritten as follows.

```
void dfs(int s)
{
    int j, k, fr;
    q.push(s);
    level[s] = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= tn; j++)
    {
        visited[j] = 0;
    }
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        fr = q.top();
        q.pop();
        if (0 == visited[fr])
        {
            visited[fr] = 1;
            item.push_back(fr);
            for (k = 0; k < edges[fr].size(); k++)
            {
                q.push(edges[fr][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this version, a node gets marked only if it is taken from the stack. Note that a check whether the node has been already visited is necessary, as a node on the stack might be visited by a later iteration. This implementation yields the sequence

```
1 2 4 8 7 3 6 5
```

which, however, is not the one described as desired solution. However, note that without additional tie-breaking rules, the [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm permits some ambiguity in the sequence of visits. The sequence

```
1 2 4 8 5 6 3 7
```

can be generated by pushing a neighbor with smallest id to the stack last, causing it to be visited in the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Codor . Now It's Working. And For Node 8, input should be in this format : 7 8 --> 6 8 --> 5 8 --> 4 8